# How to redirect payment gateway url in magento

Tags: magento, payment-gateway, payment

I am having a problem regarding payment method. I have integrated one payment gateway (like knet), but the problem is at the last I get a payment url but not a redirect in a new window. How can I redirect to the url in new window?

I used the `_redirectUrl()` method but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this code if `_redirectUrl()` not working

```
        <?php 
    Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect($url)->sendResponse(); 
        // or 
 Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect($url)->sendResponse();
     ?>
```

Comment: i used that one also,but it also not working because of i get url in json formate so that not working.